# Prepared Statements and JDBC Drivers

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the below questions on Prepared Statements in Java.

1. Is it beneficial to use Prepared Statements when the SQL Query does not have any Where clause ? Assume a simple query Select * from tablename;
2. It is said that the Prepared Statement is compiled once and only the values are substituted the second time. Hence it is faster as the Query validation and compilation step can be skipped. Where is the compiled form stored ? What is the life time of this compiled form ?

Comment: Good Detail about Pre-compilation :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497297/what-does-pre-compiling-a-jdbc-preparedstatement-do][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497297/what-does-pre-compiling-a-jdbc-preparedstatement-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A PreparedStatement is beneficial when there are parameters to be passed and when the query is to be executed repeatedly.  If there is a simple query to be fired once, a Statement will prove faster.
2. The caching takes place on DB server.  The DB server has APIs that help caching compiled queries.  Hence for repeated execution of queries, the same compiled query will run again and boost performance.

Comment: Even a simple "select * from tablename" has to be compiled and an execution plan calculated. The gain might not be tremendous tho.


The compiled form should never be re-calculated but the execution plan can, depending on changes on the implied tables or indexes.

Comment: The item #2 is not entirely true. Apps server may provides its own PreparedStatement cache, Weblogic is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use PreparedStatement everytime there's an input or more from the user. It will help you escape the needed characters to prevent SQL Injection and errors in queries.