# What does pre-compiling a JDBC PreparedStatement do?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

What does "precompiling" a statement do, because I have seen that
if I write a prepared statement with a bad SQL syntax that compilation does not report
any problem!

So if precompiling a prepared statement doesn't check for syntax validity what really does it do?

Comment: where do you expect the error? at compile time, or when you call `prepare..(..)`

Comment: This depends on the database and the driver. The JDBC spec doesn't dictate this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Creating a `PreparedStatements` may or may not involve SQL syntax validation or even DB server roundtrips, that depends entirely on the JDBC driver used. Some drivers will do a roundtrip or validate, others will not.

So on some JDBC drivers a `PreparedStatement` is no more "prepared" than a normal `Statement`. (In other words: with some JDBC drivers a `PreparedStatement` represents a server-side resource (similar to `Connection`), while on others it's a pure client-side construct).

An important difference, however is that a `PreparedStatement` will help you handle dynamic parameter values in a way that is guaranteed to avoid any escaping or formatting issues that you would have if you try to insert the values into the SQL statement string manually and execute it using a normal `Statement`.

That feature is *indepdendent* from the choice of "preparing" the statement beforehand or not, so it's provided by every JDBC driver, even if it doesn't do any other preparation steps.

Comment: ... so we can say that the method prepareStatement send to the database the SQL string for compilation and if provided the DB do a validation check. After the compiled statement, is send back, and is encapsulated into a PreparedStatement object.

Comment: @xdevel: yes, some JDBC drivers/databases do that. The server sends back a handle, usually. Then, when you execute the `PreparedStatement`, the JDBC driver simply tells the server "Execute statement 4 with these arguments: ...").

Answer (score 1):

'statement compilation' is something that happens on the database which helps it return results faster and more efficiently. If you use a PreparedStatement then it allows the database to reuse a statement which was already compiled and saves having to do it again. Bad SQL will likely result in a badly compiles database statement, but not always.