# PreparedStatement in JDBC

Tags: java, database, memory, jdbc, prepared-statement

When we are creating the Object of the PreparedStatement and execute the Query like that

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from emp");  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
```

how the Statement is recompile and PreparedStatement is precompiled?

when the data is fetched using PreparedStatement object from database at which memory location data is stored?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Java has no access to memory locations. Sounds like you need to do some more study. I suggest the Java Tutorial, [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and some googling.

Comment: visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959036/statement-vs-prepared-statement-in-terms-of-precompilation).RB i think it would be helpful...

Comment: @BasilBourque when the data is fetched then at some place it is also stored I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the JDBC engine. For instance, the JDBC engine for MySQL often doesn't actually create a server-side prepared statement (see [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946108/no-server-side-prepared-statements-using-mysql-connector-j)). In those cases, the `PreparedStatement` interface only provides a separation between the query and parameters, for clarity and protection from injection attacks; every time you execute the `PreparedStatement`, it will send over a fully-formed SQL query, which the MySQL server will then parse, optimize and execute. On the other hand, some systems (including MySQL with the right options -- see that second link) will use a "real" prepared statement, which means it'll only get parsed and optimized once.

But really, this is like asking for the memory characteristics of `java.util.List` -- it's entirely up to the implementation, and thus can't be meaningfully answered for the interface in general.

Answer (score 1):

In JDBC three things always takes place :

```
  1)Query creation.

  2)Query compilation.

  3)Query Execution.
```

In case of PreparedStatement, cache memory comes into picture hence first two steps are not needed to follow again.
Hence,only last step is executed in case of PreparedStatement which is opposite to Statement.

Comment: then what about the memory storage.

Comment: Check this http://www.coderanch.com/t/303291/JDBC/databases/Prepared-Statement-stored

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel it is appropriate :) and this explaination was given by our sir which i have posted here :)

Comment: Just note that, depending on your database, the above may not be true. :) Specifically, the query could be compiled at each invocation of `execute`, not just once.