# Updating existing Row on database jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

No error is showing when i click the button but the table on the database doesn't update.

```
String heh = jLabel17.getText();
try {
    stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE books SET availability='"+"Unavailable"+"' where Book_title='"+heh+"'");
}catch (SQLException err) {
    System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: How do you check that the table is not updated?

Comment: by going on my table on database and clicking refresh

Comment: does heh exist in ur db??

Comment: String heh = jLabel17.getText();

Comment: yes but are u sure that there is a Book_title named "jLabel17.getText()"

Comment: the label text is replaced with a book title, then i get it's text and declare it as heh.

Comment: Can you able to check your user interface having an `display row limit`, also check whether the control is coming inside the `try` statement or not

Comment: it is inside a try-catch statement

Comment: could you provide the output of System.out.println("UPDATE books SET availability='"+"Unavailable"+"' where Book_title='"+heh+"'");

Comment: Unavailable is a variable?

Comment: no it's a text that will be put on the Availability column replacing the Available text in it.

Comment: Please use a `PreparedStatement` you are wide open for SQL injection. There is also no no `commit()` in your code. Are you sure you are running in auto-commit mode?

Comment: @DOODpls try this sample query first like this `UPDATE books SET availability='Unavailable' where Book_title='yourTitle'`, if this is  not working, then please check my previous comment

Comment: i set the autocommit on the connection to false

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that query works if i put it directy on the table's query, but when i convert it into a statement it doesn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what "*put it directly on the table's query*" is supposed to mean. there is no such thing as a "table's query" and you sure can't put "a query on a table".

Comment: i dont know what im saying anymore.. what i really mean is when i put the codes in here [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2B8DAE7527F5D839!22084&authkey=!ALkp-lUv9kNFAYU&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG) it works

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up the query totally,

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE books SET availability='"+"Unavailable"+"' where Book_title='"+heh+"'");
```

should be,

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE books SET availability='Unavailable' where Book_title='"+heh+"' ");
```

It is advisable to print query before you execute , as that avoids common mistakes. Also try to use Prepared Statements as yours is vulnerable to sql injection

Read this [Prepared Statements and JDBC Drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201662/prepared-statements-and-jdbc-drivers)

Comment: If that is gonna be a `String` rather it could be availability="Unavailable"

Comment: Yeah, you are right at the same time, the OP's code will work even if there it is not variable, so this could not an answer, at the same your code or OP's code didn't declare a variable called `Unavailable`

Comment: @DOODpls Do you have an variable named `Unavailable` ? if not give it as string normally, check my update . Also print your query and check whether it runs in the database

Comment: @DOODpls put System.out.println("UPDATE books SET availability='"+"Unavailable"+"' where Book_title='"+heh+"'"); 
after excuteupdate and takeoutput .then check manually in cammandline

Comment: i made the "unavailable" into String avail = "Unavailable"; and still nothing happend

Comment: @getlost the "heh" becomes a Book Title

Answer (score 0):

AFTER HOURS OF RESEARCH, I FOUND THE SOLUTION, I REPLACED THIS

```
String heh = jLabel17.getText();

    try{
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE books SET availability='"+"Unavailable"+"' where Book_title='"+heh+"'");
        }catch(SQLException err){
        System.out.println(err);
   }
```

WITH THIS CODE

```
String heh = jLabel17.getText();

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Dafuq7","Dafuq7","Dafuq7");
                    // Creating Statement for query execution
                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    // creating Query String
                    String query = "UPDATE books SET availability='NOT AVAILABLE' WHERE book_title='"+heh+"'";
                    // Updating Table
                    int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                    System.out.println(rows + " Rows Updated Successfully....");
   } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
   }
```